# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-ms-adal'

Tags: cordova, azure, visual-studio-cordova

I have a very small sample application with authentication using the cordova plugin für microsoft azure active directory.
When trying to run the application in visual studio with with tools for apache cordova I get the following error:

```
Installing Android library: src/android/adal.gradle (TaskId:12)
1>  Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert... (TaskId:12)
1>Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-ms-adal' : error : Uh oh!
1>  cannot find "..\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-ms-adal\adal.gradle\project.properties" referenced in <framework> (TaskId:12)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this plugin on VS2013 und VS 2015 both on Windows 8.1 and Windows10 RC. All setup completly new. I cannot run an app with the plugin. It failes always with the same error. I doubt that anybody has ever run this plugin. I mean, ok, its RC but shouldn't that mean one can at least run the sample application. :-(. To be exact: I can run the sample application but not within the visual studio tools for cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the Android Platform and the CLI are you trying this on ? Note that Android@3.7.1 and Cordova CLI @4.3.0 have a a bug related to GradleReference.

We are working on a fix in the plugin that should work around this bug.

Comment: Cordava is version 5.0.0, where can I check the Android version? As I said, I'm using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova which are meant to overcome this versioning nightmare.